# A problem with the Gamow state

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space

Consider a form of potential $U(r)$ as follows
$$
U(r)=\begin{cases}0 & 0<r\leq a \\ U_0 & a<r\leq b \\ 0 &r>b\end{cases}
$$

In this problem $r$ is the distance from the origin, $r \geq 0$.

It is known that the Schrodinger equation 
$$
\left[\frac{\hat P^2}{2m} + U(r) - E\right] \psi (r) = 0
$$
admits two types of solutions: real energy solutions, with $E \geq 0$ (also named "scattering states", and complex energy solutions, with $E = E_0 - i\Gamma$ ("resonant states").

From physical reasons, both these solutions have to satisfy $\psi (r=0) = 0$.

I ask opinion about two statements.

1. The scattering states ($E$ real and positive) form a complete basis of functions according to which we can develop in a quantum superposition, any function that vanishes at $r = 0$.
2. Therefore, the Gamow state (complex $E$) can be expanded in this basis, i.e. the Gamow state is equal to its expansion in this basis.

Note: keep in mind that the scattering states are normalized to the Dirac $\delta$,

$$ \int dr \ \psi^*(r;k) \psi (r; k') = \delta (k - k'), $$

and the Gamow state diverges for $r \to \infty $.

I know that the 1st statement is correct. My question on these statements is because of things that I see quite often in the literature: the energy spectrum of a well isolated resonance, narrow and far from the threshold, is said to be distributed Breit-Wigner. But, for finding the spectrum of real energies one needs the above expansion of the resonance state, i.e. as a quantum superposition of real-energy states. But those who claim the Breit-Wigner distribution, don't do the expansion in a quantum superposition. This is what leads me to my questions.

Comment: This looks interesting. Sofia, can you explain the final paragraph a bit more so that we can understand your question? For example, you have not defined what you mean by "threshold". Can you define it?

Comment: @DanielSank : yes, of course. A resonance is an energetic level which is **not sharp**. It spreads over a range of energies. This range has a width $\Gamma $, and is centered on some central energy $E_0$. For resonances with narrow width, and well separated from other resonances, the probabilities of the energies in the range is given by the Breit-Wigner formula, or formulas very close in form to the Breit-Wigner. The narrow width and big separation from neighbor resonances avoids overlapping of the energy ranges.

Comment: @DanielSank (continuation) Well, sometimes, a factor $1/E$ appears in the formula, which means that energies close to zero should have the biggest probabilities. But, experimentally, this is not true. There is some energetic threshold for the energies in the range. Now, with resonances whose $E_0$ is close to the threshold there are a couple of problems, e.g. the Breit-Wigner form is altered (and other problems that I didn't study). This is the reason for the conditions of a clean Breit-Wigner type behavior.

Comment: It would be a good idea to add the discussion of your previous two comments into the question, trying to be concise where possible.

Comment: @annav : very well. Sometimes I see in literature something that seems to me not correct. For obtaining the BW distribution they take the factor $ e^{-\Gamma t/ \hbar}$ and do Fourier transform on it.

Comment: @annav : the fact that they should do something with the rest of the Gamow function, people ignore.

Comment: @annav I mean, please see what I do. To show that the distribution of the real energies in the resonance obeys a BW distribution, I take the wave-function and expand it in a superposition of scattering states. These states have real energy indeed.

Comment: yes , I do. My quantum mechanics book (schiff) uses an expansion too, but takes an approximation. the example is a square well.

Comment: It uses Bessel functions and then takes some assumptions

Comment: @annav : with those procedures of transforming Fourier the factor $e^{-\Gamma t/ \hbar}$ into energy-depending terms, I can't agree because the position-dependent function that follows after this factor, should be expanded as I say. It's not enough to deal with the exponential factor.

Comment: I do not think I can help you. It may be that they are using some assumptions for the particular problem that makes the rest  of the formulas insignificant?

Comment: @annav : if you can see my comment, I claim in a work of mine, that such a procedure is not correct. I just wanted to have an "second opinion", i.e. could it be that I am wrong?

Comment: @annav : some assumptions? I have to look. Well, for the moment good night. It has to be late in your country. Anyway, thank you.