# Is it possible to calculate neutron half-life theoretically?

Tags: quantum-chromodynamics, lattice-model, neutrons

Is it possible to calculate neutron half-life theoretically? For example, from lattice QCD or something?

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/31514/why-is-the-free-neutron-lifetime-so-long/31517#31517

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it has been done in [lattice QCD](https://indico.fnal.gov/getFile.py/access?contribId=12&sessionId=1&resId=0&materialId=paper&confId=5276) .

> The most studied nucleon matrix element is that of the axial charge
>   g_A. Because it can be measured precisely in neutron-decay experiments 
>   g_A provides a benchmark for of the accuracy of lattice-QCD nucleon matrix element calculations. The present quoted errors in lattice calculations of
>   g_A are 6-10%  but the lattice determinations
>   are all systematically lower than the experimental measurement by about 10%, indicating the
>   presence of an underestimated uncertainty.

Comment: I would be very glad to have some chat with you on a problem of mine. Can you have some time? It's about my question on the Gamow state, http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/154638/a-problem-with-the-gamow-state .

Comment: @Sofia  I will have a look at the question and see if I can have an opinion. It is close to my bedtime here, but we certainly could chat sometime tomorrow afternoon or evening if you are around. ( it is 22:25 here)

Comment: yes, I should also be in bed. And thank you in advance.

Comment: @Sofia well, I will be sitting close to  the computer for three or four hours